# Are cloned spieces significantly more vulnereble to deseases than sexually reproducing species?

Tags: evolution, immunology, reproduction, cloning, immunity

I would like to be able to compare the risk for species to go extinct implied by their reproduction mechanism in the very short term. Imagine we choose some species A that can reproduce both sexually and asexually and then we make three clones of earth and in one clone we spread 1 million specimen of A that are all reproduced sexually. In another one 1 million that are all asexually reproduced (not in one generation but in like a 100 generations) and in another one 1 million of cloned specimen of A. now I want to compare the probability of each of these three going extinct in 10 years assuming the next generations would also be reproduced like their parents of course.

At the end I would be happy to know if the reason I get for this question depends on how sophisticated the immune system of that specie is.

So if I can fill in the following table with normalized numbers from 1 to 100 I would be so happy.

```
╔═════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ disease toleration score    ║ clones of a single specimen ║ asexual reproduction of the same specimen through generations ║ sexual reproduction of a couple through generations ║
╠═════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ sophisticated immune system ║                             ║                                                               ║                                                     ║
╠═════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ casual immune system        ║                             ║                                                               ║                                                     ║
╠═════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ simple immune system        ║                             ║                                                               ║                                                     ║
╚═════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Right now my intuition tells me it should be something like this:

```
80 85 100
40 50 70
1  15 30
```

But I know I can be so wrong.

Please note that I don't want the single "Correct" answer to this question. I would be happy enough with the best "wrong" answer from a biologist. I mean if you know some things and you have some ideas about it that are not so bad but you are not so sure and you think maybe in future science will prove you were wrong. Just tell me that incomplete answer. I just want to learn something more than what I know now. I don't want an ultimate answer.